# Spring batch admin and starting Master/Slave jobs

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Is it possible to configure spring batch admin to start Master and slave jobs. We have one process as master and 3-4 slave nodes.

Spring batch admin is running in separate JVM process but all spring batch jobs are using same batch db schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch Admin only has the abilities to launch locally deployed jobs.  So while you can launch a job that has master/slave configurations, the job that owns the master must be deployed locally.  You could wire things up to launch remote jobs, but you'd have to wire things up yourself.

That being said, Spring XD (http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) is a distributed runtime that is able to launch jobs that are remotely deployed.

Comment: Thank you Michael. When you say, you have to wire things up to launch remote jobs, do you mean by using spring integration to invoke remote jobs?